# JUNG : Changing the vertex colour

Tags: java, jung

I have used JUNG library to visualize one network consisted of servers and links through graph.

So I initialize my graph like this, Server and Link are classes in my project:

```
            Graph<Server, Link> g;

    g = new SparseMultigraph<Server, Link>();
```

Now I need to change the color of specific vertices..
so I used the code below:

// Setup up a new vertex to paint transformer

```
    Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(Integer i) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
    };

    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
```

I got java.lang.ClassCastException exception as following!!

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: network.Server cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at GUI.GUI$9.transform(GUI.java:1)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.BasicVertexRenderer.paintShapeForVertex(BasicVertexRenderer.java:98)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.BasicVertexRenderer.paintIconForVertex(BasicVertexRenderer.java:74)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.BasicVertexRenderer.paintVertex(BasicVertexRenderer.java:37)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.BasicRenderer.renderVertex(BasicRenderer.java:70)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.BasicRenderer.render(BasicRenderer.java:55)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer.renderGraph(BasicVisualizationServer.java:367)
at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer.paintComponent(BasicVisualizationServer.java:321)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
```

My complete code to update the graph is here:

private static BasicVisualizationServer updateGraph(Network network) {

```
            Set<Server> servers = network.getServers();
    Set<Link> links = network.getLinks();
            Graph<Server, Link> g;
    // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices and E is the type of
    // the edges
    g = new SparseMultigraph<Server, Link>();
    // Add some vertices and edges
    for (Server server : servers) {
        g.addVertex(server);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (Link link : links) {
        g.addEdge(link, link.getSource(), link.getDest(), EdgeType.DIRECTED);
        i++;
    }


    // Layout<V, E>, VisualizationViewer<V,E>
    Layout<Integer, String> layout = new CircleLayout(g);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    VisualizationViewer<Integer, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<Integer, String>(
            layout);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
    // Show vertex and edge labels
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());

     // Setup up a new vertex to paint transformer...
    Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(Integer i) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
    };

    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);

    // Create a graph mouse and add it to the visualization component
    DefaultModalGraphMouse gm = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
    gm.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.TRANSFORMING);
    vv.setGraphMouse(gm);


    rightPanel.setTopComponent(vv);

    //Detecting selection of vertices
    final PickedState<Integer> pickedState = vv.getPickedVertexState();

    // Attach the listener that will print when the vertices selection changes.
    pickedState.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object subject = e.getItem();
            // The graph uses Integers for vertices.
            if (subject instanceof Integer) {
                Integer vertex = (Integer) subject;
                if (pickedState.isPicked(vertex)) {
                    System.out.println("Vertex " + vertex
                        + " is now selected");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Vertex " + vertex
                        + " no longer selected");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return vv;
}
```

Comment: What version? Link to the library? I don't see a `Transformer` or `Paint` in the "current" JUNG Javadocs.

Comment: JUNG 2.0.1   JUNG 2 depends on three other libraries: JUnit, Colt, and Common Collections.
1. JUnit:
http://junit.sourceforge.net/ 
2. Commons Collections: This stems from the Apache Jakarta Commons Collections
http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/collections/ 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/collections/  
3. Colt: http://dsd.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/

Comment: Fully-qualified class name for `Transformer` and `Paint`? Also, please post the entire stack trace, not just that you're getting a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

Comment: import java.awt.Paint;  Ok...I will post the complete error exception

Answer (score 3):

Your graph vertex type is `Server`, but your `Transformer` is expecting an `Integer` as input. You need to alter your code so that those match.

Comment: Thank you. I know this...but I need to have Vertex type as Server and not Integer...as this works when I want to show the graph, but it has problem when I want to change the colour of the vertex!

Comment: I didn't say you had to change your vertex type. Why is your `Transformer` declared `<Integer,Paint>` instead of `<Server,Paint>`?

Comment: I can not change that because setVertexFillPaintTransformer needs Transformer<Integer, Paint> as input!!

Comment: Why are you declaring `VisualizationViewer` as `<Integer,String>` if your graph is `<Server,Link>`? Did you copy and paste large blocks of code without making consistent modifications?

Comment: Thanks. Actually it was first Integer and String, You are right..I changed all of them and it works now!

Comment: @OrclUser Please remember to upvote and accept helpful answers!